# TeXnicCenter says "! I can't find file `..'."

Tags: texniccenter

My pdf fails to load and the following error occurs:

[image]

I don't know what file it's referring to.

Please help :)

I'm using the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm, todonotes, color, amsfonts, hyperref, amssymb, tikz-cd, tipa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{subcaption}
```

### Thoughts:

Perhaps my title is too long. It's 82 characters.

Comment: Is there anything else in the file? do you have an input(*) somewhere?

Comment: No, and I don't know what you mean, @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen.

Comment: it is trying to input a file that has the filename  literally `..` none of the code you show would make it do that so  it is in the code that you have not shown. (or as it is right at the start, perhaps it is an error in your editor configuration) do other files work?

Comment: Thank you, @DavidCarlisle; where do I look then?

Comment: Yes, other files work, @DavidCarlisle.

Comment: you could try to write `\end{document}` earlier and earlier, until the document is empty. Then you can pinpoint where the error is

Comment: I'll do that now, @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen.

Comment: MikTeX has an autoload feature which can be turned on, off or set to confirm.  TeXnicCenter cannot handle the "confirm" version.

Comment: What do I do about that, @JohnKormylo?

Comment: Run the MikTeX console:  the setting button on the side will show you your current option and allow you to change it.

Comment: How do I run the MikTeX console? It's not an option. There's only a settings admin and a package admin, but neither of which has an option to change the autoload feature.

Comment: The MikTeX console showed up several weeks ago during one of the updates.  Check "All Programs/MikTeX 2.9/console"

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Nope: I still can't find it.

Comment: Go to https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console and download it.

Comment: There's no need, @JohnKormylo; the issue is resolved. It was because I put a full stop at the end of the project file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a full stop at the end of the file title. I changed it by copying & pasting the text into a new project file with the same title but with no full stop. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to the specific problem, but more of a bug finding guide:

You have some document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm, todonotes, color, amsfonts, hyperref, amssymb, tikz-cd, tipa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

Super cool code that works super nice \input{coolfile}

Super not so nice code that doesnt work, not rad therer \input{..}

Super cool code that works super nice \input{coolfiletwo}


\end{document}
```

This will not compile since you only have the files `coolfile.tex` and `coolfiletwo.tex` Furtheremore the exact location of the not so cool code is hard to find. here's what you do:

You move the `\end{document}` to higher locations in the file, and that will make it compileable:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm, todonotes, color, amsfonts, hyperref, amssymb, tikz-cd, tipa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\end{document}

Super cool code that works super nice \input{coolfile}

Super not so nice code that doesnt work, not rad therer \input{..}

Super cool code that works super nice \input{coolfiletwo}


\end{document}
```

then you stepwise move the `\end{document}` through the file to pinpoint the error:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm, todonotes, color, amsfonts, hyperref, amssymb, tikz-cd, tipa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


Super cool code that works super nice \input{coolfile}

\end{document}

Super not so nice code that doesnt work, not rad therer \input{..}

Super cool code that works super nice \input{coolfiletwo}


\end{document}
```

Is still compilable *but* the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fleqn, 12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm, todonotes, color, amsfonts, hyperref, amssymb, tikz-cd, tipa}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}


Super cool code that works super nice \input{coolfile}


Super not so nice code that doesnt work, not rad therer \input{..}

\end{document}    
Super cool code that works super nice \input{coolfiletwo}


\end{document}
```

Is not!

This means that you now know that the error is in the code:

```
Super not so nice code that doesnt work, not rad therer \input{..}
```

In the real world you would offcourse move the `\end{document}` more than one line at the time. But this just shows the principle.

Comment: I just did that and nothing changed.

Comment: Did you move the `\end{document}` all the way up to right after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Yes, I did do that; still nothing . . .